# Campo de data com valor errado

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-3, razor

Tenho os campos de data:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataInicio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @placeholder = "DD/MM/AAAA hh:mm" } })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataFim, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @placeholder = "DD/MM/AAAA hh:mm" } })
```

E o *Javascript*:

```
$(function () {
    $('#DataInicio').datetimepicker();
    $('#DataFim').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: true //Important! See issue #1075
    });
    $("#DataInicio").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#DataFim').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#DataFim").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#DataInicio').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

E estava setando normalmente para o horário atual porém agora começam com os valores:

```
01/01/0001 00:00
```

Setados...

Algum erro no *Javascript* ou no *HTML*?

Answer (score 1):

Geralmente isso acontece quando o valor vem nulo, seja do banco ou quando estância o ViewModel.
Eu costumo definir minhas datas como nullable.

```
public DateTime? DataWhetever { get; set; }
```

Comment: Funcionou parcialmente, agora está permitindo setar uma data anterior a data de hoje, o que antes não era possível...